# add custom filters to the event calendar plugin programatically to frontend

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, advanced-taxonomy-queries, the-events-calendar

I want to add custom filters to the filter bar of the event calendar. I have added two dropdown as categories and location programtically, when I submit the selected filters to find events, it gives me error in console as

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`

in \plugins\the-events-calendar\src\resources\js\tribe-events-bar-min.js

I tried to print the value of e, so it is giving as

```
e = http://192.168.10.200:8181/asha/c2c/events/month/
e = 
e = 55
e = null
```

Now there are 4 filters in filter bar as

Events In - Date (Datepicker)

Search - Keyword (Input text)

Categories (Select dropdown of categories)

Location (Select dropdown of locations)

I added filter in \plugins\the-events-calendar\src\Tribe\Main.php like

```
add_filter( 'tribe-events-bar-filters', array( $this, 'setup_date_search_in_bar' ), 1, 1 );

 add_filter( 'tribe-events-bar-filters', array( $this, 'setup_keyword_search_in_bar' ), 1, 1 );

 add_filter( 'tribe-events-bar-filters', array( $this, 'setup_category_search_in_bar' ), 1, 1 );

 add_filter( 'tribe-events-bar-filters', array( $this, 'setup_location_search_in_bar' ), 1, 1 );
```

and the functions for above filters are

category filter

```
public function setup_category_search_in_bar( $filters ) {

            $term_list = get_terms( array(
                'taxonomy' => 'tribe_events_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );

            $optionsList ="";
            foreach ($term_list as $category) {

                $optionsList .= '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
            }

            if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['tribe-bar-category'] ) ) {
                $value = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['tribe-bar-category'] );
            }

            if ( tribe_get_option( 'tribeDisableTribeBar', false ) == false ) {
                $filters['tribe-bar-category'] = array(
                    'name'    => 'tribe-bar-category',
                    'caption' => esc_html__( 'Categories', 'the-events-calendar' ),
                    // 'html'    => '<input type="text" name="tribe-bar-search" id="tribe-bar-search" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Keyword', 'the-events-calendar' ) . '">',
                    'html'    => '<select name="tribe-bar-category" id="tribe-bar-category">
                                    <option value="select_category" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select category</option>
                                    '.$optionsList.'
                                </select>',
                );
            }

            return $filters;
        }
```

location filter

```
public function setup_location_search_in_bar( $filters ) {

            $venue_list = tribe_get_venues (  );

            // echo "<pre>";print_r($list);

            $optionsList ="";
            foreach ($venue_list as $venue) {

                $optionsList .= '<option value="'.$venue->ID.'">'.$venue->post_title.'</option>';
            }

            if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['tribe-bar-location'] ) ) {
                $value = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['tribe-bar-location'] );
            }

            if ( tribe_get_option( 'tribeDisableTribeBar', false ) == false ) {
                $filters['tribe-bar-location'] = array(
                    'name'    => 'tribe-bar-location',
                    'caption' => esc_html__( 'Locations', 'the-events-calendar' ),
                    // 'html'    => '<input type="text" name="tribe-bar-search" id="tribe-bar-search" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" placeholder="' . esc_attr__( 'Keyword', 'the-events-calendar' ) . '">',
                    'html'    => '<select name="tribe-bar-location" id="tribe-bar-location">
                                    <option value="select_location" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select location</option>
                                    '.$optionsList.'
                                </select>',
                );
            }

            return $filters;
        }
```

How can I get these dropdown values if selected and find events accordingly.

Thanks in advance.